# How do I use the result of one API in a second API call in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

For example, I have FindDogInfo which takes a dog_id and returns a medical_record_id, and I have another API called GetDogMedicalRecord that takes the medical_record_id.

How do I use grab the medical_record_id returned by FindDogInfo  and use it in a call to GetDogMedicalRecord?

In the project I'm working on, the useQuery hook from react-query is usually wrapping an API call and exposed as "UseFindDogInfo". Is there a way to get this sort of use the data from one API to query another API feature using react-query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re looking for [dependent queries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries):

```
 // Get the user
 const { data: user } = useQuery(['user', email], getUserByEmail)
 
 const userId = user?.id
 
 // Then get the user's projects
 const { isIdle, data: projects } = useQuery(
   ['projects', userId],
   getProjectsByUser,
   {
     // The query will not execute until the userId exists
     enabled: !!userId,
   }
 )
```